# Tiny MCE - how to save formatting with br?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom tiny mce field.
On backend side I make linebreaks, all is fine, but on the front-side there are no br, lines are like not formatted text.
Only if to add 
 tag manually it works
I tried

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_switch_tinymce_p_br' ); 

    function my_switch_tinymce_p_br( $settings ) {
        $settings['forced_root_block'] = 'br';
        return $settings;
    }
```

It only brakes all - I can't write something in tinymce.

**Everywhere I see this code**

```
tinymce.init({
   ...
   force_br_newlines : true,
   force_p_newlines : false,
   forced_root_block : ''
})
```

WHERE I HAVE TO PASTE IT? I tried to paste it in functions.php and to main.js - if in js the console doesn't know what tinymce is.Where I should place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your functions.php file and add following code:

```
function your_domain_enable_tinymce_line_breaks( $init ) {
    $init['wpautop'] = false;
    $init['apply_source_formatting'] = true;
    $init['paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste'] = false;
    $init['forced_root_block'] = false;
    $init['force_br_newlines'] = true;
    $init['force_p_newlines'] = false;
    $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true;
    return $init;
} 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'your_domain_enable_tinymce_line_breaks' );
```

It might help you to resolve this.